# How can we set shadow effect for View in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, imageview, android-view

In my Android application I have one view it may be `ImageView` or `TextView` how can I set shadow effect for View in android? I have set the shadow by using the following code, but it won't work:

`view.setElevation(130)`

Please help me to solve this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create your own "shadow view"

```
<View
android:id="@+id/shadow_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="4dp"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="@drawable/shadow_gradient" />
```

and add the shadow drawable to it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="@android:color/transparent"
        android:startColor="#8f000000" />
</shape>
```

The height is up to you, to experiment and see what works best for you as is the angle and start colour of the drawable. You just need to align this view layout to any view layout you want to have a shadow and you are good.

Comment: thanks,I need to add shadow programatically bacause On touchlistener the view is passing. ineed to set shadow for the touched view

Comment: @Resmi Just keep the view hidden by default `view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)` and when you detect a down touch set the visibility of the shadow to VISIBLE. On keyUp switch back to INVISIBLE :)